# How should I change my neural network model to make fit the last dense(2 ,activation) layer?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, softmax

I am making my first steps in Neural Network with Keras. I just try to use a 1dconv Layer, from an example that seems correct. I only change the input values shape  to fit with  my training data(2200,513) 513 corresponding the features, 2200 the length, I wish to have only two output to set if my training data correspond to my target. That's the model:

the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_37 (Conv1D)           (None, 2191, 500)         2565500   
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_38 (Conv1D)           (None, 2182, 500)         2500500   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_10 (MaxPooling (None, 727, 500)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_39 (Conv1D)           (None, 718, 160)          800160    
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_40 (Conv1D)           (None, 709, 160)          256160    
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_10  (None, 160)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 322       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,122,642
Trainable params: 6,122,642
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

when I train the data I have this error, that my last layer doesn't have the proper size of (674197,)... I am puzzled, any help?

I have already changed the last layer to a size 674197 but it makes no sense, and the training stop after two epochs without improving.

```py
model_m = Sequential()
model_m.add(Conv1D(500, 10, activation='relu', input_shape=(2200,513)))
model_m.add(Conv1D(500, 10, activation='relu'))
model_m.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model_m.add(Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu'))
model_m.add(Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu'))
model_m.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format='channels_last'))
model_m.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_m.add()
model_m.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (674197,)

I expect that the output should be 2 so I want to keep this shape, I should modify some part of the model but which?

Comment: The problem is in the data, the error is about the target having shape (674197,), while (2,) is expected. Why do your labels have that shape? (674197,)

Comment: Yes (I feel  dumb), in fact I use some stupid code to change my label's target into vector wich shape was 674197  length. That's been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

So the error wasn't coming from the model but from a code that change the label string of the target to some vector, the ugly part was like this :

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
listNumTarget=[int(la,32) for la   in label_target_list]
target=to_categorical(listNumTarget)
```

I wasn't expecting that behaviour of the "to_categorical"  function, but it's seems that this function  output is vector with only "0" and only one "1", it expects also that the labels all exists from 0 to the max number you pass to the function. So the output length is the max of the number you pass to it, even if you have few labels in your list.